# if array is full and its size is increased by 1 to insert the new element.time to insert

Tags: arrays, time-complexity

If an array is full and its size is increased by 1 to insert the new element, time to insert N elements can be calculated as 1+2+ .. N = N^2/2.   Why? Been Watching algorithm of Princeton still couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a simple example. Suppose you have an array of 100 elements that's totally full, and you want to add another element to it to get 101 total elements. How much work do you need to do? Well, you need to

1. create a new array of size 101,
2. copy all 100 of the previous elements over,
3. toss your old array, and
4. snap the new element into position.

The total work here is going to be proportional to the size of the original array (here, 100) because most of the work is spent setting up, copying, or tearing down an 100-element array. So even though it's not 100% correct to say that we have to do 100 units of work to perform the above operations, let's just pretend that that's the case.

How much work would it take to do the above if the original array had 137 elements in it? Probably about 137 units of work. If it had 500 elements, it would be 500 units of work, etc. More generally, if the array has n elements in it, let's say that we do n units of work.

So now, let's imagine you start with an empty array. Adding the first element takes 1 unit of work, the second takes 2, the third takes 3, etc., because in each case you're doing a number of units of work proportional to the size of your array.

So how much work is that in total? Well, the total work you'd do if you have n total elements is

> 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + (n-1) + n.

This is a famous sum called Gauss's sum, and it's know that

> 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + (n-1) + n = n(n+1) / 2.

If you're not sure why that is, do a quick Google search. There are some beautiful explanations as to how this happens.

That last term can be rewritten as

> (n<sup>2</sup> - n) / 2

and since the n<sup>2</sup> term is so much bigger than the n term, this effectively comes out in the long run to be roughly n<sup>2</sup> / 2 units of work. That doesn't scale very well with n, which is why, generally speaking, you don't see people resize arrays this way.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. But I still don't understand why does adding the first element need 1 but adding the second element needs 2? Isn't the first element and second element are both separate unit? and when you say"The total work here is going to be proportional to the size of the original array" what does the total work mean? Is it the work of completing the total 100 units?